# JSON response laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel-4

I'm am very new to using JQuery and Ajax so what I am struggling with may be simple.

I have a laravel method that returns a JSON response. I am calling the method in AJAX which returns the data correctly as shown below

```
{"contribution_id":"72","name":"October 2133","at_total":"12","at_key_accounts":"12","at_targeted_accounts":"12","at_sundry_accounts":"12","at_new_business":"12","yd_total":"12","yd_key_accounts":"12","yd_targeted_accounts":"12","yd_sundry_accounts":"12","yd_new_business":"12","created_at":"2014-09-16 15:17:05","updated_at":"2014-09-16 15:17:05"}
```

In my view I am trying access each part of the data individually. I can alert all of the JSON but I am unable to just return one of the variables.

This is my AJAX code, it alerts "undefined"

```
<script>
var con_id = $("#con_id").val()
$.ajax({
  url: "/tpquarterly/laravel/public/getContribution/" + con_id,

  context: document.body
}).done(function(data2) {

    alert(data2.contribution_id)
  $( this ).addClass( "ere" );
});
```

Comment: You are trying to access a var out of scope there, use `con_id = $("#con_id").val()` not `var con_id = $("#con_id").val()`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make any difference. I still am able to get all of the data from "data2" if I put alert(data2). I want to get only part of the array, but when I put alert(data2.contribution_id), the alert says undefined

Comment: Try to convert the JSON string into an array and then access it with square brackets: `var data = $.parseJSON(data2);` then access it `alert(data['contribution_id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify dataType option in your ajax call like below

```
var con_id = $("#con_id").val()
$.ajax({
   url: "/tpquarterly/laravel/public/getContribution/" + con_id,
   dataType: "json",
   method: "GET",
}).done(function(data2) {
  alert(data2.contribution_id)
  $( this ).addClass( "ere" );
});
```